# How to fix issue linking with Provider my store and passing data to components in my Redux-React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(WebShop)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(WebShop)".
```

Even though I have wrapped my components in a `<Provider>` tags and linked it to my store. This is my `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

import App from 'views/App';
import Home from 'views/Home';
import Webshop from 'views/webshop';
import Cart from 'views/webcart';



ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={ hashHistory }>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Route path='/' component={ App }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
                <Route path='Webshop' component={ Webshop } />
                <Route path='Cart' component={ Cart } />
            </Route>
        </Provider> 
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app') // eslint-disable-line
);
```

My `store.js` is:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import  reducer  from './reducers';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';


var initialState = {
  cart:"medium",
  data: [],
  url: "/api/comments",
  pollInterval: 2000
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    createLogger(),
    thunkMiddleware
  )
);
export default store;
```

I'm using `connect` in my `webshop.js` where I use :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onCartAdd: (cart) => {
            dispatch(addCart(cart));
        },
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(WebShop);
```

If more code is needed to find a solution let me know. Now, I'm not sure if this error is coming from the `webshop.js` file or the linking between the components and the store. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: For one, your providers need to be on the very outside of the routes.

Comment: You may also need to wrap your routes in a function, such such as ```{()=>()}```.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Check whether you are passing `store` correctly by adding `console.log(store)` line before `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: I get `Object {dispatch: function, subscribe: function, getState: function, replaceReducer: function, Symbol(observable): function}` @TharakaWijebandara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the order of router and provider.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={ hashHistory }>
            <Route path='/' component={ App }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
                <Route path='Webshop' component={ Webshop } />
                <Route path='Cart' component={ Cart } />
            </Route>
        </Router>,
    </Provider> 
    document.getElementById('app') // eslint-disable-line
);
```

Comment: I tried this before, but for some reason it was giving me an error..but now it's fine so..thanks.